# Email enabled list/library missing attachments

Tags: 2010, document-library, attachments, incoming-email, email-enabled-library

I have an email enabled library that accepts attachments, saves original emails, and accepts emails for any sender. The problem is, that I can email this email address along with several other people, and the users will receive the email with attachments, but the SharePoint library will not.

I've read some articles on adding ADSI attributes to the email address, but I've tried that.

What's going on here?